# MSMessages Extension iOS 10 Removing the Message UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am currently building an iOS 10 MSMessages Extension App. I am displaying a screen as an .expanded state of my MSMessages. When I click on the UITextField it displays a Keyboard but right above the keyboard it also displays the TextField for messages. I want to hide that TextField since there is no use for that in the expanded state screen. Here is the screenshot of iMessage TextBox that I want to hide in the expanded state.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to do this in the current beta (Xcode 8 beta 6). If this is something you want in iMessage apps, I would suggest submitting a bug report / feature request on Apple's developer website so they are aware that this is an important issue to developers.